# Multiple installation of XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to get multiple installed versions of XAMPP.

I'm just renamed folders /opt/lampp to lampp5 and install new with php7 but somehow when I start lampp 5 I find out that all my databases in MySQL have gone away and there is new dB's from php7 installation.

Why databases are erasing and how can I avoid it? Maybe it's related to mysql socket but I do not know deeply how it works in xampp

Comment: out of curiosity - how comes you're not just apt-getting it all? A lot easier than XAMPP - relating to the actual task, I'm guessing that it uses a general storage location, not relative to version of xampp, so each time you install a new instance it overrides that folder and empties it out

Comment: Yeah, you can't just rename folders and change the structure of installed programs and expect it to keep working. You need to change the XAMPP config to point to the new folders

Comment: Main question is why you would want multiple installations and if the answer is to use different versions then look into either using Docker or virtual machines.

Comment: @NigelRen you are right, but unfortunately, my work pc to slow to use virtualization

Comment: @FMashiro change config before installation?

Comment: @bxN5 no, you've edited the folder structure of lamp5, so you need to go through all the config files to find corrupt paths, in the OLD installation, and edit those to fit your new directory structure.

Comment: Try and limit the options to one version of MySQL (if you can) which will limit the combinations you have to manage.

Answer (score 0):

When i migrated to PHP7 using xampp, i just exported/imported database to new system. Simply start 5, export all, close 5, open 7, import all.

Comment: I do not want to migrate, I want to have multiple versions

Comment: I have two versions, but only one can run at once...if you want to use old mysql with new php, you need to start mysql from control panel for xampp with php 5 and apache from xampp with php 7...sice they are two separate programs/versions too. Maybe you will need to play with config files a little bit, However, imho the easiest way is to export/import as i aswered. 3min work.

Comment: no, I want to run each at once, old database just disappear